# How to solve Android Arm64-v8 memory operation(memcpy, GetByteArrayRegion, SetByteArrayRegion) crash

Tags: android, memory, java-native-interface, arm64

I have an Android project with two JNI functions which operate memory.(**Github: [android_memcpy_test](https://github.com/sanqianpiao/android_memcpy_test)**)

Otherwise, a UnintTest(named **ByteUtilTest**) is written to verify those two JNI functions.

#### When I run UnintTest under ARM32-v7 it's success, but it doesn't work under ARM64-v8.

I have spent 2 days on solving this problem but failed, any help will be appreciated!

---

**JNI functions**

[image: JNI functions]

**Unit Test**

[image: Unit Test]

**Error Logs Under ARM64-v8**

```
07-01 17:00:14.160 360-360/? I/DEBUG: pid: 2929, tid: 2952, name: roidJUnitRunner  >>> com.example.sanqian.android_memcpy_test <<<
07-01 17:00:14.160 360-360/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xffffff918160c0
07-01 17:00:14.169 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x0   0000000012d701ec  x1   ffffffff918160c0  x2   0000000000000008  x3   0000007f987fb000
07-01 17:00:14.169 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x4   0000007f987fed48  x5   0000007f9717d000  x6   0000000012d701ec  x7   ffffffff918160c0
07-01 17:00:14.169 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000001  x9   0000000012d701ec  x10  59e6183118387b72  x11  0000000000000001
07-01 17:00:14.169 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x12  000000007020f958  x13  00000000fffffff8  x14  0000007f91791ac0  x15  0000000000000000
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f987fb0d8  x17  0000007f9bfbf888  x18  0000007f91791ac0  x19  0000000012d701e0
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f918135c0  x21  0000007f988a7000  x22  0000007f987fb000  x23  0000000000000000
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000008  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000007f91791e00  x27  0000000000000008
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     x28  0000007f91791a58  x29  0000007f91791960  x30  0000007f985ebddc
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f91791960  pc   0000007f9bfbf8f0  pstate 0000000080000000
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000000158f0  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+104)
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000027cdd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI23SetPrimitiveArrayRegionIP11_jbyteArrayaNS_6mirror14PrimitiveArrayIaEEEEvP7_JNIEnvT_iiPKT0_+1016)
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000eed68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI18SetByteArrayRegionEP7_JNIEnvP11_jbyteArrayiiPKa+136)
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000000076c  /data/app/com.example.sanqian.android_memcpy_test.test-2/lib/arm64/libandroid_memcpy_test.so (Java_com_example_sanqian_android_1memcpy_1test_ByteUtil_copyByteArray+88)
07-01 17:00:14.170 360-360/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000199a34  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.sanqian.android_memcpy_test-2@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Answer (score 3):

> When I run UnintTest under ARM32-v7 it's success, but it doesn't work
>   under ARM64-v8.

Fix this:

```
void *handle;
 .
 .
 .
return (jint) handle;
```

Pointers likely fit into 32-bit integers in a 32-bit memory model.  Pointers ***DO NOT*** fit into 32-bit integers in a 64-bit memory model.

If `sizeof( jlong ) >= sizeof( void * )`, you can return a `jlong`:

```
void *handle;
 .
 .
 .
return (jlong) handle;
```